# Masonry plugin not working

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, layout, grid, masonry

I have just started to use the masonry plugin but I cannot get it to work. Below is a picture of the problem.

[image]

As you can see this is not the desired effect. Below is my code that I am using:

CONTENT

```
    <div class="container" id="reviews">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="comment-block">
      <div class="new-comment"></div>
        <?php 
          while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
            $data = mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($con, "SELECT first_name, last_name FROM transactions WHERE order_id = '{$row['order_id']}'"));
            $name = $data['first_name']. ' '. mb_substr($data['last_name'], 0, 1);
            if($row['rating'] == 5) $star = '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star review_star"></span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star review_star"></span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star review_star"></span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star review_star"></span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star review_star"></span>'; 
            if($row['rating'] == 4) $star = '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star review_star"></span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star review_star"></span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star review_star"></span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star review_star"></span>'; 
            if($row['rating'] == 3) $star = '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star review_star"></span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star review_star"></span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star review_star"></span>'; 
            if($row['rating'] == 2) $star = '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star review_star"></span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star review_star"></span>'; 
            if($row['rating'] == 1) $star = '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star review_star"></span>'; 
          ?>
          <div class="col-md-4">
            <div id="box_review">
              <h3><?php echo $star; ?></h3>
              <h5 class="thin"><?php echo $row['date'] ?></h5>
              <blockquote>
                <p><?php echo $row['comment'] ?></p>
                <footer><?php echo $name ?></footer>
              </blockquote>
            </div> 
          </div>
        <?php } ?>
    </div><!-- ./ comments block -->
  </div><!-- ./ row -->
</div><!-- ./ container -->
```

MASONRY

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
  $('#reviews').masonry({
   columnWidth: 400,
   itemSelector: '#box_review'
  }).imagesLoaded(function() {
   $('#reviews').masonry('reload');
  });
});
```

Please can you help me with what I am doing wrong? I am using Bootstrap for the grid system as well by the way I am not sure if that might be the problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should apply bootstrap's `col-md-X` classes to your blocks because you are explicitly telling masonry that the minimal width of your blocks is 400 pixels and bootstrap's col-md-X can vary depending on the screen's resolution.

1. Define the minimum width of your blocks (just like with the old [960 grid system](http://960.gs/) that is up to 16 columns (which means 60 pixels minimum). 400 pixels seems a lot, no ? So let's say 100px.
2. Define a new class, let's say `.masonry-normal-grid` and apply it to your blocks.

In CSS, create

```
.masonry-normal-grid {
    width:300px;
}
```

You can also create .masonry-small-grid or .masonry-large-grid as long as thecolumnWidth defined in javascript represents the lowest width of your classes (you should not have a CSS class width smaller than the javascript attribute columnWidth).

Important : Id **MUST** be unique ! So rename `<div id="box_review">` into `<div class="box_review">` (and change in your javascript attribute #box_review into .box_review too)

Note : You should do `if elseif` instead of only `if` (or even a `switch(case)`).